# Tracking usage day by day for db table

Tags: mysql, database, analytics, theory

I have about 100,000 artists/bands in my database.  I want to be able to track views for each band, so for instance, if I'm viewing Pearl Jam metrics, I want to be able to see on 1/1/2012 they saw 10,000 views, on 1/2/2012 they saw 12,000 views ... and so forth.

What is the best way to capture this data?  I'm not looking for code help, more looking for theory/suggestions.

I was thinking of doing the following:

1. Hits table for artists.  Every time Pearl Jam (or any other artist) is viewed, then insert a new row to track this view (include artist id and timestamp).
2. Run a nightly script on these rows for the last 24 hours.  Group and count by the artist id.  Insert this count into a new table for each artist for that specific day.
3. Truncate this hits table so it doesn't grow incredibly huge.
4. Do a select for the artist id in order to grab views.

Is this correct line of thinking?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I'm the developer of an open source analytics platform [Countly](http://count.ly) and wanted to share my experience with you.

Inserting a new row for each view to an artist and map-reduce those results every day is for sure a solution (it is actually the solution that have been used by older analytics solutions) but there is a better approach you can choose. This approach however requires the use of a document oriented database just like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/).

When there is a view to the artist you will do an increment to the related fields just like;

```
db.views.update({'artist_id': 1}, {
    '$inc': {
        "views": 1,
        "2012.views": 1,
        "2012.8.views": 1,
        "2012.8.4.views": 1
    }
})
```

And you will get a document inside views collection just like below;

```
{
    "artist_id": 1,
    "2012": {
        "8": {
            "4": {
                "views": 1 /* today */
            },
            "views": 1 /* august */
        },
        "views": 1 /* 2012 */
    },
    "views": 1 /* all time */
}
```

This solution requires no batch processing and in fact is in true real-time. If you want to check all the stats for August just fetch the results like below and you will have data for all days in August plus the total views in August itself.

```
db.views.findOne({"artist_id": 1}, {"2012.8": 1})
```

Or if you need just a total views for 2012;

```
db.views.findOne({"artist_id": 1}, {"2012.views": 1})
```

You can take a look at [MongoDB PHP driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/) assuming that you are using a LAMP stack.